# I have a cyclical event, every 3 years, sheet has to show either "closed", "canceled" or "current"

Tags: schedule

I have an excel sheet, events are rows, years are columns, events happen every 3 years.
if the event is closed, it is scheduled for 3 years ahead.  If the event is canceled it is scheduled for the next year, then if it happens it gets scheduled for 3 years ahead, if it is current it stays that way until it is changed to closed.
The sheet must say closed, canceled or current in the cells of the event/year it happens.
**canceled only happens before event.

I've tried many statements and not getting anywhere.
I expect the cell that's in the row/column to say either "Closed", "Canceled" or "Current"